# solving ages in simultaneous equation topic

Tags: linear-algebra

Larry Is currently twice as old as Bill. Below are my workings:

L= 2B or B=2L

Is larry older than Bill? or Bill is older than larry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larry is twice as old as Bill. So age of Larry is more than Bill. What is bigger? $2B$ or $\frac B 2$? (Age is obviously positive)

Comment: 2B is the answer

Comment: Good­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­